# Jquery .on() with delegate does not respond to dynamic html with events bound to anchor tags

Tags: jquery

This is part of my `$(document).ready`

```
$("#dynaffiliate").on("click", "a.ajaxpaginate", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

`<div id="dynaffiliate">` exists at pageload.

When I inject a bunch of a elements with that class, the event is not fired. I'm using firefox. I've also tried using just plain `a` with no class and nothing happens..

Now, I am also thinking deeper into this - an `a` element may be impossible to handle in this manner - since the browser will just navigate to the link before it has a chance to bubble the event up to the parent. Am I better off using some other element instead of an `a` tag?

Comment: *the browser will just navigate to the link before it has a chance to bubble the event up to the parent* No, that's not true, the default action will only take place after the bubbling phase if it was not cancelled. Are the new elements all descendants of `#dynaffiliate`? If not it won't work, if yes, it should. I suggest you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.7 or higher? `dynaffiliate` has to be the parent. Are you trying to trigger the event on that element?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsbin.com/ugiket/2/)… how’s your situation different from this example?

Comment: @Purmou `dynaffiliate` can be any ancestor that is not being destroyed by the Ajax event. It doesn't have to be the parent.

Comment: @Purmou - dynaffiliate is a parent and exists. The version is the issue and works great. I'm converting someones old app to ajax and they had 1.5. Before I do anything else in a project from now on I'm going to verify versions. Delegating events like this is also very fast, because I may have hundreds of added categories(to flip to any page in a drop down) and there is only one event handler at the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in all browsers. Aren't you reloading DIV?

```
// e.g.
$('#dynaffiliate').html('<a class="ajaxpaginate">Link text</a>');

// instead of
$('#dynaffiliate')
    .html('<div id="dynaffiliate"><a class="ajaxpaginate">Link text</a></div>');
// or
$('#dynaffiliate').append('<a class="ajaxpaginate">Link text</a>');
```

It might also be possible you are using jQuery version prior to 1.7. You should see error message in Firebug console in that case.

Comment: The browser version was the issue. Works amazing now. Thanks